# Find Last Percentage Distribution Excel

Tags: excel

Im having trouble for find last 10% distribution and return Index% 1-10.

[image]

just like image below

[image]

Thanks Before
Regards

Answer (score 0):

As a result of my understanding you need a formula like this:
(Your sheet starts at A1 and Index(%) start in B2 and end in K2)

```
=IF(K2>=10;10;IF(SUM(J2:K2)>=10;9;IF(SUM(I2:K2)>=10;8;IF(SUM(H2:K2)>=10;7;IF(SUM(G2:K2)>=10;6;IF(SUM(F2:K2)>=10;5;IF(SUM(E2:K2)>=10;4;IF(SUM(D2:K2)>=10;3;IF(SUM(C2:K2)>=10;2;IF(SUM(B2:K2)>=10;1;0))))))))))
```

I can give you an answer in VBA like this:
(Alt+F11 to load Visual Basic => Add a module)

```
Public Function getresult(row As Integer, startCol As Integer, endCol As Integer, resultValue As Integer)
   Dim i As Integer, sum As Double
   sum = 0
   For i = endCol To startCol Step -1
       sum = sum + Val(Cells(row, i))
       If (sum >= resultValue) Then
           getresult = i - 1
           Exit Function
       End If
   Next i
   getresult = 0
End Function
```

and use it like this:

```
= getresult(ROW();COLUMN(B2); COLUMN(K2);10)
```